# How to use avg function?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, average

I'm new at php and mysql stuff and i'm trying to use an avg function but i don't know how to.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Did not connect to $database");

mysql_query("AVG(column1) FROM table1 ") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

echo AVG(column1);
```

(Q1)I'd like to see the value printed in the screen, but i'm getting nothing but an error message. How could I print this average on the screen ?

(Q2)If I had a column month in my table1, how could I print the averages by the months ?

Sorry for any bad English, and thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for Q1:** `SELECT AVG(column1) FROM table1`

**Solution for Q2:** `SELECT AVG(column1), month FROM table1 GROUP BY month`

Answer (score 1):

What to read?

1. [MySQL `SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)
2. [MySQL `AVG()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) - there is even an example of exactly what you need
3. [PHP `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) which is one of several ways to retrieve data from result set
4. btw: [PDO](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is much better for database communication in PHP

Ad. 1:

```
$sql    = 'SELECT AVG(col_name_1) AS avgColName FROM tbl_name;';
$query  = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

var_dump($result['avgColName']);
```

Ad. 2:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY MONTH(date_col_name);
```

Comment: I'm getting it like this 'string(6) "3.5000"', 3.5 is the correct avg, can i print it without the string(6) and wihtout the "" ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Of course... just take a look on what [`var_dump()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) does. Use [`echo`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of the query into a variable which you can then use.

For example:

```
$query = "AVG(column1) FROM table1";     
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['AVG(column1)'];
}
```