# Creating query for printing average of two months

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to show monthly average of total using SQL and PHP.
For example this table has total=254 in June & total=315 in July. I need to show their average i.e. (254+315)/2= 284.5

What SQL query should I make to print their average using PHP?

[image: The data of table is..]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010715/how-to-use-avg-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use avg function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010715/how-to-use-avg-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
select sum(total) / count(distinct extract(year_month from date))
from t;
```

This sums the `total` column and divides by the number of months.  If you need this for the particular two months, then include a `where` clause:

```
select sum(total) / count(distinct extract(year_month from date))
from t
where date >= '2020-06-01' and date < '2020-08-01'
```

If you wanted to count missing months as `0` for the average purposes, then use a constant:

```
select sum(total) / 2
from t
where date >= '2020-06-01' and date < '2020-08-01'
```